# Svg element is not displayed inside ScrollView if I try to use flex in React Native

Tags: svg, react-native, scrollview

I want a page with a Svg graph at the top and some text explaining it under the graph. The text is long so the page must be able to scroll. When I use fixed width and heigth on the Svg element it works but I want to use flex.

This is an example with a simple rectangle instead of a graph. The Svg rectangle does not show:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ScrollView} from "react-native";
import Svg,{  Rect} from 'react-native-svg';

export default class MyScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
       <Svg style={{flex:1,alignSelf: 'stretch'}} viewBox='0 0 300 200'>
            <Rect x={10} y={10} height={180} width={280} stroke="#000" fill='none' />  
        </Svg>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <Text>Very long text that does not fit on one screen...
            </Text> 
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

When I search I find suggestions to use contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}} instead of style={{flex:1}} in the ScrollView. When I try this, the Svg element is displayed but then, the text that ends up outside the screen is outside the scrollview as well. You can see the text but the scrollview bounces back when you try to scroll to it. Note. You need a long text to reproduce this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox-Layouts and Scrollviews are always a bit tricky, because if you think about flexbox itself it tries to position elements relatively to height and width at the same time. In a ScrollView, the height should not be 100%. Moreover the `<View>`-Components around the `<Text>` and `<Svg>` are not needed.

So in your case I would try to remove all flex-styles inside the Scrollview and replace them with `Dimensions.get("window").width` instead. You could do the same with the height. Here is a small example I've fiddled in expo, so give it a shot.

[Expo Example](https://snack.expo.io/Syzs_j5OG)

EDIT: Found an article today on exactly your Problem, maybe you could give it a shot: [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@peterpme/taming-react-natives-scrollview-with-flex-144e6ff76c08)

Comment: Thank you for the great example. Using Dimensions.get("window").width as you did works fine, but unfortunately the width will not update automatically when I toggle between landscape and portrait as it does when I use flex. This was the reason why I wanted to use flex all the way. I started out using Dimensions... and then I used "react-native-orientation" to handle the orientation change. This worked but I got performance isuses when the graph re-rendered.

Comment: Maybe you could try to fiddle around with width:"100%" or have a look at the article i added in my answer.